# How can I convert PHP array to accociative array

Tags: php

I want to convert this array based on array value.

Before underscore value is convert to key and after '_" value is convert to value

Original array

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 1_1 
  [1] => 1_2 
  [2] => 1_3 
  [3] => 1_4 
  [4] => 1_5 
  [5] => 1_6 
  [6] => 3_1 
  [7] => 3_2 
  [8] => 3_4 
  [9] => 3_5 
  [10] => 4_1 
  [11] => 4_2 
  [12] => 4_3 
)
```

I want to convert it to :

```
Array(
  [1]=> array(
    [0]=>1,
    [1]=>2,
    [2]=>3,
    [3]=>4,
    [4]=>5,
    [5]=>6
  ),
  [3]=> array(
    [0]=>1,
    [1]=>2,
    [2]=>4,
    [3]=>5,
    [4]=>5
  ),
  [4]=> array(
    [0]=>1,
    [1]=>2,
    [2]=>3
  )
);
```

Comment: Where is your code? Post it...

Comment: Hi! Stackoverflow is a specific problem solving community, not a free coding service. Please show us what you have done, what problems you encountered and what you expected. Also, this question has been answered at least 50 times, so some more research might do you good too.

Comment: a combination of `foreach` and `explode`, then using exploded items as key pair and new assignment into a new container should suffice

Comment: Sure I saw this question yesterday. And I probably said the same thing then. It would be better to look at the code that creates this array in an unusable state and fix the problem there

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job :

```
$array = Array (
  0  => "1_1",
  1  => "1_2",
  2  => "1_3",
  3  => "1_4",
  4  => "1_5",
  5  => "1_6",
  6  => "3_1",
  7  => "3_2",
  8  => "3_4",
  9  => "3_5",
  10 => "4_1",
  11 => "4_2",
  12 => "4_3"
);

// Create a new empty array
$result = array();

// Loop throught your first array
foreach ($array as $data) {

    // Foreach data, you explode by '_'so you will get an array
    // Eg. $new_data = array(0 => '1', 1 => '1') for $data = "1_1"
    $new_data = explode('_', $data);

    // Now you just have to add the data as you want
    $result[$new_data[0]][] = $new_data[1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

The output is :

```
array (size=3)
1 => 
array (size=6)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => string '5' (length=1)
  5 => string '6' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '4' (length=1)
  3 => string '5' (length=1)
4 => 
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thanks it's working :) . And one more question what is the reverse process to reconvert original array ?

Comment: Foreach + string concatenation? Loop throught the array `foreach ($result as $key => $data)` then loop throught each $data `foreach ($data as $index => $value)` and you will get each "old" value with `$old_value = $key . "_" . $value;`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$resp = [];
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $values = explode('_', $a);

    $resp[$values[0]][] = $values[1]; 
}
```

For the reverse:

```
$resp = [];
foreach ($resp as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $resp[] = $key . '_' . $a;
    }
}
```